Call a Rest API without FE application for every 10mins
I want to schedule a GET API call every 10 minutes without using a front-end application.
Note: Unable to use the scheduler, because of my requirements.
Consider my API is https://xvyz.com/keep-alive
Is there any possible way to achieve this API call without opening an application or using Front end!

Your hosting provider should have a mechanism for "keep-alive" and you don't have to find workarounds  for it. For Example in Azure: Enabling Health Check will keep the application alive as they continuously ping the health check endpoint in a specific time. However a better way to keep the application alive is by using the setting AlwaysOn within Azure App Service settings.

I can't try that because I'm using the free version of the Render deployment.

The best solution is to use a scheduler which is available in your programming language, (java has its own scheduler) using this scheduler call the method of the API every 10 minutes.

You can also use a cron job, on the server you can add a cron job and trigger the API call every 10 minutes
setting cron job in unix
cron job every 10 minutes
*/10 * * * * curl -X POST -d '{"message":"content"}' https://xvyz.com/keep-alive


You can use setInterval() for your purpose. The below script will call the API at 10 minutes interval.
setInterval(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
}, 600000)


It will work if the front-end application is open in the browser. If it's not open anywhere, my question is how to call the API without the front-end and scheduler.

you can use serInverval on your project.

Also you can create/use CronJob to call the api without running the FE.
